# Limit the maximum value of the composition of an integer

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, integer-partitions

I was doing a coding test (already finished, so no cheating for me) and came across this problem, which I'll describe in few steps:

1. We have a keypad, like on cellphones, with **keys from 1 to 9**, where 1 is the space key (" ")
   [image]
2. We are given a message to convert to numbers based on the "distance" of each letter (P = 7, S = 7777, K = 55, ...), for example **DRSA** becomes **377777772**
3. Now we need to calculate the the **number of the possible messages** we could write with that same number (DPPPPPPPA, DPPPPPQA, ...)

---

The method I came up with is the following:

1. I split the number by its different digits obtaining for example **3, 7777777, 2**
2. I ignored single digits as they do not add "value" to the permutations (as far as I understood it)
3. I take each section of digits and based on its length (in this case **7 digits**) I calculate every possible permutation and **count** them

---

Now this method works, but it's slow so I wanted to find a way to calculate the number of these permutations without counting them manually.

I found out about **integer compositions**, which in my case should have a maximum value. In this case **the key 7 has a maximum value of 4** so its composition would be something like this:

- 4+3
- 3+4
- 4+1+2
- 4+2+1
- 1+2+4
- 1+4+2
- ...

How can I limit the maximum value of the composition (4) of a number (7)? How can I know the number of elements in it?

Answer (score 1):

For numbers limited to $3$ you have the Tribonacci numbers, [OEIS A000073](http://oeis.org/A000073), which begin $$ 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 44, 81, 149, 274, 504,$$ and for numbers limited to $4$ you have the Tetranacci numbers, [OEIS A00078](http://oeis.org/A000078) which begin $$ 1, 2, 4, 8, 15, 29, 56, 108, 208, 401, 773, 1490,$$
Each number in the Tribonacci series is the sum of the previous three, because to get a composition of $n$ you can take a composition of $n-1$ and add a $1$, a composition of $n-2$ and add a $2$, or a composition of $n-3$ and add a $3$.

Comment: Didn't know this one! Could you explain to me the last part, because I didn't understand it, what do you mean by "to get a composition of n you can take a composition of n−1 and add a 1, ..."?

Comment: And if I had a key with 5 characters? I would use something like a "pentanacci"? [OEIS A052918](https://oeis.org/A052918)

Comment: The last justifies the recurrence.  If I have a composition of $13$ and are limited to $3$, consider the last digit.  If it is $1$, you have a composition of  $12$ left when you erase the $1$, so the number of ways to get $13$ is the sum of the ways to get $10, 11,$ and $12$ because you can append the appropriate digit at the end.  Yes, if you had a key with $5$ characters you would have each number the sum of the preceding $5$ for the same reason.

Comment: @Xriuk It is not A052918. For numbers limited to $5$ we get [A001591](https://oeis.org/A001591)  "Pentanacci numbers"

Answer (score 0):

> How can I know the number of elements in it?

Two-variable recurrence. If $a_m(n, k)$ is the number of compositions of $k$ numbers from $1$ to $m$ which total $n$ then $$a_m(n, k) = \begin{cases}
0 & \textrm{if } n < 0 \\
1 & \textrm{if } n=0, k=0 \\
0 & \textrm{if } n=0, k \neq 0 \\
\sum_{i=1}^m a_m(n-i, k-1) & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

For practical computation, you would want to use dynamic programming.